# Computation of Riemannian Hessian of the Stiefel manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hessian-matrix, frechet-derivative

I am fairly new to differential geometry, so I'm sorry if I am sloppy in my notations.

In the book [Optimization Algorithms on Matrix Manifolds](https://press.princeton.edu/absil), the Riemannian Hessian is given by [definition 5.1](https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/absil/Absil_Chap5.pdf) as:

$$Hessf(x)[ξx] = ∇_{ξx} grad f $$

Where $f$ is a real-valued function on $M$, ξx $\in$ $T_xM$ (tangent space of M), and ∇ is the Riemannian connection on $M$.

Using the definition of the Riemannian connection for the Stiefel manifold (eq. 5.17):

$$∇η_X ξ = P_X (D ξ (x) [η_X ])$$

With $P_X$ the projection to $T_xM$. We can then write the Riemannian Hessian as:

$$ Hessf(x)[ξx] = P_X (D grad f (x) [ξx ]) $$

Now my questions are:

- What is the operator $D$  in this equation?
- How would I "evaluate" at $ξ$? Do I just multiply this tangent vector with the resulting Hessian matrix?

My guess is that to somehow match the Euclidean Hessian, $D$ should be the Jacobian. What confuses me is that this operator is used both for scalar-valued, as well as for vector-valued functions.

Comment: $D$ is the usual covariant derivative in your ambient space.  In this case it is the familiar Jacobian in Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\rgrad}{\mathrm{rgrad}}$
$\newcommand{\grad}{\mathrm{grad}}$
$\newcommand{\hess}{\mathrm{hess}}$
$\newcommand{\rD}{\mathrm{D}}$
$\newcommand{\rP}{\mathrm{P}}$
Try this :-).
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10957-023-02242-z,
read cube:
https://rdcu.be/ddyWJ

which also has the Stiefel manifold formula worked out.

In matrix/vector calculus language, $\rD$ is just the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative). Thus, $\rD F(x)[\xi_x]$ is just the directional derivative
$$\rD_{\xi_x} F(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}(F(x+h\xi_x) - F(x)).$$
This is well-defined for a tangent vector $\xi_x$ at $x$. But yes, $\rD$ is probably more properly defined as the covariant derivative in the ambient space.
Covariant derivative is defined for vector fields, but in any case - the evaluation is the above directional derivative. Here, we extend a function on the submanifold $M$ (the Stiefel manifold in this case) to a function $F$ in the ambient space near $M$. The main idea is $\rD_{\xi_x} F(x)$ could be evaluated by calculus.

For the case $F$ is the Riemannian gradient $\rgrad_f$, for $f(x) = x^TAx$, the Rayleigh quotient for a symmetric matrix $A$, for example, then $\rgrad_f(x) = 2\rP_xAx$. Here, the ambient gradient is $2Ax$ by calculus,  $\rP_x$ is the metric-compatible projection to the tangent of the Stiefel manifold, using the embedded metric - as is the case in the book,
$$\rP_x\omega = \omega - x(x^T\omega)_{sym}$$
where $X_{sym} = \frac{1}{2}(X+X^T)$.
Thus:
$$\rgrad_f(x) = 2Ax - 2x(x^TAx)_{sym} = 2Ax - 2xx^TAx,\\
\rD_{\xi_x}\rgrad_f(x) = 2A\xi_x - 2\xi_xx^TAx - 2x\xi_x^TAx - 2xx^TA\xi_x
 $$
and the Riemannian Hessian is $\rP_x\{\rD_{\xi_x}\rgrad_f(x)\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Two remaining questions:

1. How did you obtain the last equation (D)? This seems to be replacing  every time x or x^T appears. Is it using the inner product of the gradient with ?

Comment: 2. You mentioned "Px is the metric-compatible projection", but the derivation of Px I have seen does not depend on the metric explicitly. I am interested in using the canonical metric (instead of the embedded) so the Hessian ends up looking as in eq. (2.55) of [this paper](https://math.mit.edu/~edelman/publications/geometry_of_algorithms.pdf) or eq. (5.4) of the paper you sent. Is this just the same formula $P_X$ (Dξ (x) [ηX ]) with a different projection than the one given by the embedded metric?

Comment: $\newcommand{\rD}{\mathrm{D}}$
So  $\rD_{\xi_x}F$ is the directional derivative $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{t}(F(x+t\xi) - F(x))$. It could be computed by usual calculus rules, except there is no commutativity. So $\rD_{\xi_x}x=\xi$, which is clear if you use the definition $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}((x+t\xi) - x)$,
directional derivative of a sum is sum of derivatives,  and $\rD_{\xi}(A(x)B(x)) = (\rD_{\xi}(A(x))B(x)  + A(x)(\rD_{\xi}B(x)) $, hence $\rD_{\xi}(xx^TAx) = \xi x^TAx + x \xi^TAx+ x x^TA\xi$ by using the product rule repeatedly. This is related to the Jacobian, or differential of a map.

Comment: For a scalar function, it is the inner product of the gradient with $\xi$, but you usually compute the gradient by taking directional derivative then extract out the variable $\xi$. For Stiefel manifolds, the projection is the same for both the embedded and the canonical metrics, using equation 5.2 . The Riemannian gradients are different, as you can see from the formula right below it for $\Pi_gg^{-1}$. In general the projection is metric dependend, in this case they happen to be the same. May be helpful to go through the code for proj or projection in open source manifold packages.

Comment: But the definition I use in my initial question [(5.5.1)](https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/absil/Absil_Chap5.pdf) for the hessian should still be valid as long as I use the correct Riemannian connection and gradient, right? Any open source project you recommend?

Comment: sure - $\nabla_{\xi_x}grad_f$ is a definition of the Hessian. I just try to answer your question - what is $D_{\xi}$ and how to evaluate it. I think Manifolds.jl or geomstats has both canonical and embedded metrics. I remember manopt has the embedded metric only but that may change since the last time I looked.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you the explanation was super useful! I was just making sure the initial formula for Hess was still valid since I find it easier to implement numerically than eq. (5.5)